# Reference on Poincaré residue in higher dimension and for poles of order $>1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\res{res}$I'm looking for a good reference on residues in the following setup:

$X$ a smooth $n$-dimensional algebraic variety, $D$ a SNC divisor on $X$, and $\omega$ an algebraic $n$ form on $X\setminus D$ (with poles of arbitrary order along $D$).

I'm then looking for a notion of residue that allows me to associated to $\omega$ an $n-1$ form $\res(\omega)$ on a component of $D$, in such a way that the integral of $\res(\omega)$ over an $n-1$ chain $\gamma$ in $D$ is equal to the integral of $\omega$ over some tube $T(\gamma)$ over $\gamma$ in $U$.

I think the construction $\res(\omega)$ should exist, but I can only find information on the case where $\omega$ has a pole of order $1$. I would be especially interested in a way to explicitly compute $\res(\omega)$.

Comment: Have you looked at the Atiyah--Hodge paper (Annals 1955)?

Comment: There are also the articles of Griffiths, "On periods of certain rational integrals, I and II".  These are the articles where Griffiths shows how to use the "Griffiths residue calculus" to describe the Hodge structures of hypersurfaces (and complete intersections, etc.) in projective space.

Comment: @JasonStarr I'm not that well-versed in Hodge theory. Could you give a more precise pointer to a place in the articles where this is discussed? I can find some things Griffiths did on the residue of a form at a point (when the denominator consists of generators for the ideal defining the point), but this is not precisely what I'm interested in.

Comment: You can find it in page 488-490 in "On the Periods of Certain Rational Integrals, I" of Griffiths. The key idea is to reduce the order of poles of $\omega$ (at the cost of being more anti-holomorphic), see Lemma 8.7.

Comment: @AGlearner Thanks! That's great