# Precise reference in Griffiths' papers : computation of the Hodge theory of a smooth projective hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

The papers *Periods of integrals on algebraic manifolds* by Griffiths is often quoted as the first instance where the Hodge ring of a smooth projective hypersurface (say defined by the homogenous polynomial $f$) is related to the jacobian ring of $f$.

However, this paper is divided in three parts of equal length (about 70 pages each, so more than 200 pages in total) and the references I have don't give the precise section nor a set of pages where the result might be found. I have tried to flip through the paper but with this superficial approach, I haven't been able to locate the computation of the Hodge ring of a smooth projective hypersurface in terms of the Jacobian ring of the homogeneous polynomial defining it.

Does anyone know the precise location of this computation in Griffth's papers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the story about Griffiths’s notebooks?

Comment: @JasonStarr : No. But in case you know the precise location of the computation of the Hodge ring of a smooth projective hypersurface in terms of the Jacobian ring of the associated homogenous polynomial, and you can tell it to me, then I would be very grateful!

Comment: I will get it later this evening.  Usually I cite the Griffiths residue calculus from an article of Voisin and an article of Carlson and Toledo.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414376/reference-on-poincar%C3%A9-residue-in-higher-dimension-and-for-poles-of-order-1

Comment: What is the story about the notebooks?

Comment: Griffiths would fill a notebook with new math theorems.  When the notebook was done, that was an article to be sent off for publication.  Then he would start a new notebook.  It sounds dubious to me, but it would explain the "Periods" articles.

Comment: Also, I think the original proof of Clemens-Griffiths was supposed to be a "specialization-deformation" argument, closer to what Collino eventually produced.  Once Clemens and Griffiths found their proof that applies to all smooth cubic threefolds (rather than just "sufficiently general" a la Collino), they had already written down so much of the other argument that they decided to leave it in.  That is why there is a length digression in the middle of Clemens-Griffiths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the post pointed out by Jason, the correct reference is *On the Periods of Certain Rational Integrals II* by
P. Griffiths,
Ann. Math. 90, no. 3 (1969), pp. 496-541. The best place to look at is §10, where the results are explained using sheaf cohomology.

Comment: are you sure section 10 is the correct section. I agree the cohomology of differential operators on $X$ is somehow related to the cohomology of the open complement of $X$. But I see no instance of the result I am looking for.

Comment: This is Theorem 10.8. You have to make explicit what he calls $\mathcal{K}_k(V)$, but that's straightforward.